# How do I convert this sql string into an ibatis sql string?

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

My sql string looks like this. And What I'd like to do is change it into a format ibatis can use

```
SELECT distinct( dbo.vwChangeMgmt1.number ) 
  FROM dbo.vwChangeMgmt1, dbo.vwChangeMgmtTask1
 WHERE dbo.vwChangeMgmt1.Asgn_Group != 'WTO-AMS-NOVUS' and     
       dbo.vwChangeMgmtTask1.Resource_group = 'WTO-AMS-NOVUS' and
       dbo.vwChangeMgmt1.number = dbo.vwChangeMgmtTask1
```

My Ibatis code

```
    SELECT * from
    vwChangeMgmt1 e, vwChangeMgmtTask1 f where
    (
    e.Asgn_Group != 'WTO-AMS-NOVUS' and
    f.Resource_group = 'WTO-AMS-NOVUS' and
    e.number = f.PARENT_CHANGE)
```

The problem with this is duplicates, and the DISTINCT portion returns errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I needed to change my result map line. the part in bold was added on the unique field.